# Is there a way to use laravel 4.2 authentication without a database?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-4

I am currently developing one plugin of a few larger projects. To make testing easier, I created a separate project and will copy the code to the different projects after the plugin is well-tested.

The plugin will be using the authentication methods of the bigger project, so I don't want to create another one during testing. However, as some functions require testing with authentication, I will need to try using the authentication class with minimal set-up. So, is there a way to use the authentication class to do simple login/logout without a database?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need your own auth auth provider.

You can read about it in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers)

*Edit:* 
Laravel 4.2 [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/extending#authentication)

Comment: Sorry, that is for laravel 5. Any reference on laravel 4?